# C#: Get folder ownership problem

Tags: c#, directory, file-permissions

I am trying to get the ownership of a protected file in C#.

```
System.Security.AccessControl.DirectorySecurity Sec = new DirectorySecurity(directory, AccessControlSections.All);
```

is not working for me. I get the error UnauthorizedAccessException. So I cannot change the owner of the file and I cannot edit my access rights. Does anyone know a way how to set the directory permissions?

Comment: Could you add the version of the OS you are running and whether or not you are running UAC (if appropriate) and are running the code as an administrator?

Comment: I am using Windows 7, the UAC is disabled and I am running my program as an administrator. That should not be the reason. When I change the owner in windows explorer, my code works. But I cannot change the owner programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mike O'Brien published a nice blog post solving my problem:
http://blog.mikeobrien.net/2009/11/taking-ownership-and-setting-admin.html
This allows me to take over ownership of any folder.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you (or the user that  you're application is running under) doesn't have access to the directory that you're trying to get access to.

Comment: No the user does not have access to the file. But I am admin on my PC. My system owns the file. I need to get access to it.